# SQL70527 error in database project

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-project

I have a database-project, created based on my existing database. It also added the scripts for creating users. One of those scripts is =>

```
CREATE USER [JOOS_NT\Indigo.Development] FOR LOGIN [JOOS_NT\Indigo.Dev.svc];
```

This script works fine on my database. But in my database-project this script is throwing an error when I build it. The error is:

```
"SQL70527: 'JOOS_NT\Indigo.Development' is not a valid name because it contains characters that are not valid."
```

It seems the "\" in the `[JOOS_NT\Indigo.Development]` is not allowed. However on the database itself I can run the query and it works fine. If I change it to `[JOOS_NT/Indigo.Development]` I don't get the error, but when comparing the scripts in the project to the existing database, it would drop the user (`[JOOS_NT\Indigo.Development]`) and replace it with (`[JOOS_NT/Indigo.Development]`)

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, when I change to script to CREATE USER [JOOS_NT\Indigo.Dev.svc] FOR LOGIN [JOOS_NT\Indigo.Dev.svc]; it works fine. But why doesn't it work with the original script ?

Answer (score 1):

Answering for someone who will look in the future.

On the database project, if a '\' character is included in the user name, the login should match the user name.

Because that, this don't work:

```
CREATE USER [JOOS_NT\Indigo.Development] FOR LOGIN [JOOS_NT\Indigo.Dev.svc];
```

But this will:

```
CREATE USER [JOOS_NT\Indigo.Development] FOR LOGIN [JOOS_NT\Indigo.Development];
```

Or

```
CREATE USER [JOOS_NT\Indigo.Dev.svc] FOR LOGIN [JOOS_NT\Indigo.Dev.svc];
```

I'm not sure if this is the expected behavior or a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.  The core issue is that in the "CREATE USER FOR LOGIN" based on a windows user login, if you are using a domain name for the user then this must match the login's domain name + login name.  See this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4c601532-809e-4cdc-bd90-9223c3085cd7/bug-getting-sql70527-for-create-user?forum=ssdt) on MSDN