# Why am I getting this error from azure sql? Error Code [70527]

Tags: sql, azure, cloud

I am encountering this error in azure SQL [70527] any suggestions on how to fix this? This is the first time I have encountered this error.

[image]

I would appreciate any advice at all, I'm at a loss how to fix this issue, I am not well versed with azure SQL at all

Comment: Was this database uploaded from a local SQL Server?

Comment: @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP yes it was imported from a local server

Comment: @IvanApungan can you show us more details about the error title?

Comment: Take a look at this article on "partially contained databases" and the issues of where a user is defined. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are migrating a database from on premise sql serve to Azure. I suggest you use the migration agent which will highlight all these issues with possible resolution in some cases.
The error code 70527 is related to user login which is highlighted in the following post as well

[SQL70527 error in database project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425006/sql70527-error-in-database-project)

You may have to create the user as per suggestion in the post above using the script method rather than the backup restore.

You can download the migration agent from below link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595